# Cheapest way to get from SFO to Stanford?

Tags: sfo, san-francisco-bay-area, silicon-valley

I'm flying into San Francisco and need to get to a house near Stanford University. Anyone have good/bad/fun experiences they'd recommend?  Besides walking.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please define what you mean by "best." I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how to write good, answerable questions.

Comment: BART to Millbrae, Caltrain to Palo Alto station, total $14 peak.

Comment: Cheapest is relative.  What is your budget?  Walking is essentially free.

Answer (score 5):

The cheapest public transit option that I can find seems to be SamTrans bus 398 or KX to any stop on El Camino Real, and then SamTrans bus ECR to Palo Alto, for a total of $4.50 ($2.25 for each bus).

Comment: 398 is convenient, but only runs once an hour: http://www.samtrans.com/schedulesandmaps/timetables/398.html - route 292 runs every 30 minutes.

Comment: @GeorgeY.: True, but you would need to take 292 to Hillsdale and 292 goes on circuitous local routes to get to Hillsdale, whereas 398/KX also go to Hillsdale but on the freeway, so is *much* faster. So I am not sure it would actually save time to take 292 most of the time.

Comment: Depends on time; after 4pm if it goes down 101, this is not going to be much faster.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Bay Area! Enjoy the weather, forgive the traffic!

Now, depending on what you consider the best:

- Fastest: taxi (unless you arrive in rush hour). Expect to pay $60-100.
- Reasonably fast: shuttle. $29 on SuperShuttle.

If you have few bags:

- Slow and not-so-cheap: BART + Caltrain + Stanford shuttle/walk. Around $10. Could be 1-2 hours, as BART and Caltrain are not time-synchronized. You'll need to buy separate tickets too. Note that on weekdays during the daytime you will have to take BART to San Bruno station, there change to another BART to Milbrae, and only there take Caltrain. Weekends and evenings BART from SFO goes directly to Milbrae.
- Cheapest: SamTrans bus 292 to Burlingame (California Ave; ask about Burlingame Caltrain station if unsure), couple minute walk to Caltrain station, and Caltrain to Stanford. $6. Bus accepts cash only and gives no change; have coins.